# How to deal with UnsafePointer<UInt8> in Swift 3

Tags: swift3

I downloaded this code from https://github.com/jrickard/BLEBasics.git
and it was written in **Swift 2** when i want to compile it into **Swift 3** their is an error occurring that says: **"Ambiguous use of init"**

```
var notMuch: Int = 0
let notMuchNS = Data(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(&notMuch), count: sizeof(Int))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Data(bytes:count:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1780158-init) takes an `UnsafeRawPointer`, not an `UnsafePointer`. You can simply pass `&notMuch` like so:

```
let notMuchNS = Data(bytes: &notMuch, count: MemoryLayout<Int>.size)
```

Also, there's no `sizeof` in Swift 3, use `MemoryLayout<T>.size` instead.